# Update Alamofire to use Swift 3

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I was using Alamofire using Swift 2 in my XCode Project. After the release of XCode 8, I need to use Swift 3 to compile my application. I use Alamofire in my project so I made the following change in the Podfile for it to use Swift 3:

```
pod 'Alamofire',
:git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
:branch => 'swift3'
```

This gives me an error when I run a `pod update` stating that the branch is not found. I wonder if there is anything else which needs to be run before I do a pod update or some other branch URL.

Comment: The swift3 version is already merged with the master branch. Just make sure you're using version 4.0+ and you should be ok.

Comment: okay. i tried it initially(a lot of times) with that and it just won't work. somehow it did now. XCode :/ Thanks a lot!

Comment: Try to update specific pod file somtimes it will try to update every pod which is listed in podfile so try 'pod update Alamofire'

Answer (score 0):

**First of all**

1. Update your Cocoapod `pod repo update`
2. Open your Podfile
3. Add this, Alamofire need ios 9.0 for Swift3

```

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
   end
  end
end
```

4. Add `pod Alamofire`
5. install `pod install`

then Alamofire 4.0.1 should be installed